# Pixelated reflections in eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, glass, reflection

I created a glass material using the Principled BSDF node. I have a high resolution hdri set as the world environment texture.

However the reflection in the glass material looks very pixelated.

[image]

Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I found the solution. In render settings, go to Indirect Lighting and increase the Cubemap Size. Increasing Filter quality also helps.